# HTML file upload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take a file input in the following way:

```
Input file: <input type="file" name="-f" id="fa">
```

I want to add an HTML link `(upload example)` so that it will upload an example file on clicking it without opening the file upload window. I tried the following:

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('fa').files[0].name = 'http://localhost/EXAMPLE/example.txt'; return false; ">(upload example)</a>
```

But it is not working. How shall I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You make FormData for it, now file[0].name is overwrite.

```
<a href="" onclick="fileAppend('http://localhost/EXAMPLE/example.txt'); return false; ">(upload example)</a>

function fileAppend(file){
var Form = new FormData();
Form.append(file);
console.log(Form);
}
```